# How do I make two elements align side-by-side in a different width container?

Tags: html, css

For example:

```
<!-- make sure the link block fulfill the whole container -->
a {display:block;float:left;border:1px solid #ccc; width:48%}

<!-- work great in width:400px; -->
<div id=container1 style="width:400px">
  <a href="" >first element</a>
  <a href="" >second element</a>
</div>

<!-- not good! no enough space for second link block in my situation test in firefox-->
<div id=container1 style="width:200px">
  <a href="" >first element</a>
  <a href="" >second element</a>
</div>
```

So, is there a way to make them all fulfill and align side by side in **different width of containers!?**

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're making a list of links - if this is the case, you should use (instead of `<div>`) the `<ul>` tag with `<li>` and `<a>` inside.

If you do this you can apply the `width`/`float` rules to the `<li>` instead, and apply the `border` and `display: block` to the `<a>` tag.

I changed your `width` to `50%`, as that's obviously what you're trying to achieve.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/LNb78/)

---

Here are two alternate solutions which will work only in modern browsers/IE8+:

1. You can use the `outline` property instead of `border`.
   See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline
   [***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/tzYHg/)
2. You can use `box-sizing: border-box`.
   See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing
   [***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/dhj6b/)

Answer (score 0):

Set margin:0; padding:0; for both container1 and a tags. That could be the problem.in